# How do I stop windows from "refreshing" connected monitors when plugging in a new one?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10-v20h2

So here's how things work;
say you have 2 monitors in one system. Then you put 1 VMs on each monitor on fullscreen then "dedicate" peripherals to each VM.
and boom! you got two computers that your kids can play roblox in.
after they're done playing, you remind them to unplug the monitor to save power and prevent oled burn-in. so, one of them unplugged the monitor (like a good boi.). Then the other one keeps on playing (cuz he have a problem). Then the other one came back (cuz reasons) and then plugged the monitor back. *and then doodoo happens*! upon connecting the new monitor, the other one (the already connected one) blinks for a good 1 and a half second. The addict gets mad and retaliates by  plugging out his monitor and connecting it when the other one is in a life or death scenario (In roblox! in F- roblox!). Anyone have ideas how to stop the blinking behavior in windows 10 20H1?

Comment: Why unplug the monitors? Putting them to sleep is enough.

Comment: And you can hook everything up to a powerstrip with a switch (and hook up PC and monitors to it), and ask the last one playing to turn off the whole thing. Additionally, there are fancy versions out there that turn off the entire strip if the 'master' contact (i.e. the PC) stops drawing power. I'd go for a simple switch one though, both for cost and teaching purposes :)

Comment: Eco Power Strips typically work with a master/slaves ports.

Comment: That's the one, wasn't sure of the term.